Casting pointer to an array of integers to matrix of integers
I am trying to use access to dynamically allocated memory as if it was a matrix, as to make my code easier to read and interpret.
int *mem = (int *) calloc(10, sizeof(int));

*(mem + 5) = 10;

int (*mat)[5][2] = mem;

printf("%d", (*mat)[2][1]);

// I used type 'int[5][2]' where arithmetic or pointer type is required
printf("%d", ((int[5][2])mem)[2][1]);

// It works, but I can't figure out why because "int[5][2]" is already a
// pointer so wouldn't "int(*)[5][2]" be the adress of mem?
printf("%d", (* (int (*)[5][2]) (mem))[2][1]);

I, however, cannot find a way to cast a pointer to an array of integers to a matrix of integers.
I tried both casting directly to a matrix, but it seems like it has issues with the type.
I also tried tricking the compiler by declaring a pointer to a matrix of said size, which works, but it kind of defeats the purpose of declaring the memory on the heap and then having to declare an extra pointer on the stack.
And the last attempt is to cast to a pointer of an array and then dereference it, but this would add more work and longer syntax than just casting to a matrix, defeating the point of making the code easier to read.

Arrays are not pointers. An array can decay to a pointer to its first element. So if you have int array[SIZE]; then array will decay to &array[0].

And generally, if you ever need to create such complex expressions and casts, then you should take it as a sign that you should refactor the code to make it more readable, understandable, and maintainable.

To use the allocated memory as an array of 5 arrays of 2 int, simply use a pointer to an array of 2 int, and allocate space for 5 of those:
int (*mat)[2] = calloc(5, sizeof *mat);

By analogy, when you want an array of int, you use a pointer to an int, not a pointer to an array of int. In both case, the type you use is a pointer to the first element of the array, not a pointer to the array. In the case of an array of 5 arrays of 2 int, its first element is an array of 2 int, so you use a pointer to an array of 2 int.

This is the syntax that fit my idea the best ((int(*)[2])mem)[2][1] = 10; throws no errors or warnings and has the functionality i was looking for

@iongigel: If you use the declaration specified in the answer, then the type cast that you use in your comment is not necessary, because the pointer mem already has that type.


int (*mat)[5][2] = mem; This is invalid C, the pointer types are not compatible. We may regard the chunk returned from calloc as some sort of int array, where the size and dimensions are unknown to the compiler.
You would need to use an explicit cast: int (*mat)[5][2] = (int(*)[5][2])mem;. Such casts are usually dangerous and bad practice, but will work in this specific case.

printf("%d", (*mat)[2][1]); will then work as expected.

(int[5][2])mem is invalid since you can't cast something to an array type. You'd have to cast to a pointer to array type as in my previous example.

(int (*)[5][2]) (mem) is the appropriate cast and followed by de-referencing with *, it will give you the expected array indices. If you didn't de-reference it but just went (int (*)[5][2]) (mem))[2][1], then this would be pointer arithmetic on array basis, as is the 2 in [2][1] would represent 2 items each with type int [5][2]. And that's not what we have here (it would have been a 3-dimensional array), so that would crash the program.

Remember to call free() at the end.


